# Python SQL Query Error: TypeError: expecting string or bytes object

Tags: python, sql, typeerror

I have a python program that makes an SQL query to an Oracle DB using a query saved in a text file *.sql as shown below. I'm getting a "type error" as TypeError: expecting string or bytes object pointing to line with sql = query. I have not been able to solve it. Here is the program:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from sys import exit


conn= cx_Oracle.connect('DOMINA/S#U@ex021-orc.corp.mycompany.com:1540/domp_domi_bi')
# READ SQL QUERY FROM FILE
with open(r'C:\Users\Au321103\.spyder-py3\Validation\DOMINA_query.sql') as f:
    query = f.readlines()
# IMPORT INTO PANDAS DATA FRAME
try:
    df = pd.read_sql(con = conn, 
                     sql = query)     # QUERY READ FROM .sql FILE
finally:
    conn.close()
df.head()

exit()
```

Thank you in advance as I'm trying to learn these db queries.

Comment: The `readlines` returns a *list* of strings while `pd.read_sql` wants a string. If you know the query is 1 line, you could pass `query[0]`, otherwise something like `" ".join(query)`

Comment: Or just replace `f.readlines()` with `f.read()`